# Serverless framework serverless-offline start error on get request cannot find module 'node:url' (Lambda AWS)

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, serverless, serverless-framework, serverless-offline

I have the following issue...
turns out I cannot test locally my aws lambda function over serverless-offline plugin in serverless framework for nodejs. Cannot do a simple GET request.

I am able to deploy to aws lambda with `serverless deploy` command, but in order for better development experience of the team we need to deploy locally with serverless-offline, I followed this guide https://fauna.com/blog/develop-using-serverless-offline, but got stuck when I do a simple get request after running successfully `serverless offline` command.
This I get when running `serverless offline` successfully
[image: serverless offline command output]

But when I do a get request to the link `http://localhost:3000/` through postman
I get the following error

[image: get request error]

It basically says cannot find node:url module but I did npm install url, but still same error throwing.
I will insert the project tree and files below:

[image: serverless hello world tree structure]

handler.js

```
//"use strict";

console.log("AJAJAJAJAJAJAJAJAJAAJAJ");

console.log("Printing module");
console.log(module.exports);

module.exports.hello = async (event) => {
  console.log("whaaaaat");
  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify(
      {
        message: "Go Serverless v3.0! Your function executed successfully!",
        input: event,
      },
      null,
      2
    ),
  };
};
```

serverless.yml

```
org: ortizjorge97
app: aws-node-http-api-project
service: aws-node-http-api-project
frameworkVersion: '3'

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs14.x

plugins:
  - serverless-offline
  - serverless-bundle
  - serverless-dotenv-plugin

functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello
    events:
      - httpApi:
          path: /
          method: get
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "aws-node-http-api-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "<!-- title: 'AWS Simple HTTP Endpoint example in NodeJS' description: 'This template demonstrates how to make a simple HTTP API with Node.js running on AWS Lambda and API Gateway using the Serverless Framework.' layout: Doc framework: v3 platform: AWS language: nodeJS authorLink: 'https://github.com/serverless' authorName: 'Serverless, inc.' authorAvatar: 'https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/13742415?s=200&v=4' -->",
  "main": "handler.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "serverless-bundle": "^5.5.0",
    "serverless-dotenv-plugin": "^4.0.2",
    "url": "^0.11.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "serverless-offline": "^10.2.0"
  }
}
```

I am newbie on aws stuff, so I dont know what could be happening.

I am using

- node 14.17.2
- MacOS Monterey m1 processor

Comment: what do you get when you try to require the url from the nodejs cli. And could you please check whether the url module exists in the node_modules/ directory?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the actual serverless package itself as a dev dependency. Try this:

`npm i -D serverless`

**Noted:** remember to check the documentation of serverless-offline to know find the supported version of serverless package.

Answer (score 0):

I fount in too
node 14.17.3, framework 3.25.0 (local), plugin 6.2.2, SDK 4.3.2

I can workaround fixing by change require to import in UserFunction.js

[img.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ve8QT.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

set your node version to 16.17.0 or higher, and install serverless as a dev dependency

Answer (score 0):

This happens because your version of Node **14.17.2** does not support node:url package anymore, as node:url was deprecated and removed.

Either downgrade your Node version to 12.x or downgrade your serverless-offline package to **^8.8.1**